# Change Firstname & Lastname order in the order-processing e-mail templates

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

in the Hungarian language we generally use the Lastname + Firstname format when we communicate with each oter. Therefore I would like to change this method in Woocommerce and special in the client e-mail?

Where can I edit this emial template or should I use rather a filter?
Thank you for your replies in advance!
Joseph

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround solution and it works, but not the most beautiful:

```
// I made the original action passive
// do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

// ... create a new solution from scratch 
$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

//to escape # from order id 

$order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number()));
echo $order_id;

echo '<h2>' . __( 'Customer comments', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h2>';

$text = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $order_id)); 
echo $text;

?>

<table id="addresses" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top;" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" valign="top" width="50%">
        <h3><?php _e( 'Számlázási cím', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3> 
        <?php 
                echo $order->get_billing_last_name() . " ";

                echo $order->get_billing_first_name() . "<br />";

                echo $order->get_billing_address_1() . "<br />";   

                echo $order->get_billing_address_2() . "<br />";   

                echo $order->get_billing_postcode() . "<br />";

                echo $order->get_billing_email() . "<br />";

                echo $order->get_billing_phone() . "<br />";

                ?>
    </td>
    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" valign="top" width="50%">
                <h3><?php _e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
                <?php 
                echo $order->get_shipping_last_name() . " ";

                echo $order->get_shipping_first_name() . "<br />";

                echo $order->get_shipping_address_1() . "<br />";

                echo $order->get_shipping_postcode() . "<br />";                
                ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your store's email templates, go to WooCommerce > Settings > Emails 
from here you can edit your email template.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately there is no option to change the order of firstname and lastname.